# If statement syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a exercise on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets) where I'm asked to compare a set of triplets to get a score. After my initial submission I wanted to try something more elegant (that is to say with less conditionals) so I made the following code:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
    # Complete this function
    aS = 0
    bS = 0

    alpha = [a0, a1, a2]
    beta = [b0, b1, b2]

     (1..3).each do |i|
         if (alpha.(i) > beta.(i)) then aS++ end
         if (alpha.(i) < beta.(i)) then bS++ end
     end   

    return aS, bS

end
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
solution.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
.(i) > beta.(i)) then aS++ end
                              ^
solution.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
.(i) < beta.(i)) then bS++ end
                              ^
solution.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

If I remove the `end` of each if statement I get a new error that says the syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end is on the `end` of the class.

My best guess is that I'm not properly closing or constructing my if, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no increment operator `++` in Ruby, instead use `value += 1`.

Try with:

```
def solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2)
  aS = 0
  bS = 0

  alpha = [a0, a1, a2]
  beta  = [b0, b1, b2]

  (0..2).to_a.each do |i|
    aS += 1 if alpha[i] > beta[i]
    bS += 1 if alpha[i] < beta[i]
  end   

  [aS, bS]
end

p solve(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
# => [0, 3]
```

In Ruby you don't need to specify the `return` it'll be the last value you put within a function (or scope), also you must want to transform to array your range (1..3), and as you're using every index of it to check in your `alpha` and `beta` arrays you'll get `nil` when the index take the number 3, because there's no index 3 on those arrays, try instead with `(0..2).to_a`

To increment your initial variables use `+=` instead `++` and to check the index of arrays you can do it with square brackets `alpha[i]` (isn't needed to write with a dot, or as methods).

To return more than one value, try this time doing it as an array, just "plain" objects will throw `syntax error`.

`if ... then ... end` can be shortened as `do_something if this_happens`

Answer (score 4):

Ruby does not have an increment unary operator. Instead do `bS+=1`. See the following as an example of the fix using `irb`

```
irb(main):001:0> x = 2
=> 2
irb(main):002:0> if x > 1 then x++ end
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> if x > 1 then x+=1 end
=> 3
```